# Android use Interface inside activity

Tags: android

In my application I have simple interface class as :

```
public interface IOnFinishProgressBarLoading {
    public void onFinish(boolean status);
}
```

and into activity I'm using some `Fragment` and I'm try to use implemented interface inside `Activity`. for example:

```
public class ActivityBootstrap extends FragmentActivity implements IOnFinishProgressBarLoading{

    ...
    @Override
    public void onFinish(boolean status) {
        if (!status) {
             pb_retreive_data.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
             pb_retreive_data.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

now my problem is use that implemented interface from `Activity`, for example

```
public class FragmentMessagesList extends Fragment {

        ...

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           ...
           IOnFinishProgressBarLoading.onFinish(true);
           ...
        }
}
```

I get null exception error, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the possibility to get your activity through the fragment calling `getActivity()`.

Now you can cast this activity eighter to `ActivityBootstrap` or `IOnFinishProgressBarLoading` and call the `onFinish()` method.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    ((IOnFinishProgressBarLoading)getActivity()).onFinish(true);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override onAttach method like this:

```
IOnFinishProgressBarLoading callback; 
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {

        try {
            callback = (IOnFinishProgressBarLoading) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Parent Activity must implement IOnFinishProgressBarLoading");
        }

    super.onAttach(activity);
}
```